# How do we delete our apps "Data & Documents" when developing on Unreal Engine for iOS?

Tags: ios, xcode, arkit, unreal-engine5

We published an app for iOS which accidentally stores a ton of photos in "Data & Documents". The app is live on the App Store, but currently the only way for a user to delete this bloat is to uninstall and re-install the app. Updating does not delete it.

We fixed the bug, and put in a notice on the App Store page, but we'd rather take care of this on our end.

The app was developed using Unreal Engine 5.1.1. The bloat is caused by Apple ARKit having had the `should_write_camera_image_per_frame` turned on (see https://docs.unrealengine.com/5.0/en-US/PythonAPI/class/AppleARKitSettings.html). The images are saved to `Container/Documents/CameraImages`.

How can we make it so the next version we push to App Store will delete the contents of this folder upon launch?

Comment: You could likely do this with [`FileManager.removeItem`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/filemanager/1408573-removeitem) if you know where these files were stored, or if they follow a specific format. Were they in a certain folder, or are the file names formulaic?

Comment: Can I call that from unreal engine?

Comment: I'm unsure... https://docs.unrealengine.com/5.1/en-US/BlueprintAPI/FileUtils/DeleteFile/ might be usable. If you're using C++, then https://forums.unrealengine.com/t/method-to-delete-a-file-using-c/143679 might be the solution. [Here are the docs](https://docs.unrealengine.com/4.27/en-US/API/Runtime/Core/GenericPlatform/IPlatformFile/DeleteFile/) for that.